# stumped by simple groovy variable comparison

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script (a Jenkins pipeline) and a simple variable comparison is not working like I expect.  I have a class defined to hold some constants, like this:

```
class email_when {
    static final int ON_FAILURE =  0
    static final int ALWAYS =      1
}
```

At a certain point in the script I set an environment variable to one of these states, like this:

```
env.EMAIL_WHEN = email_when.ALWAYS
```

Then later, I check the value.  This check is always failing and I don't understand why.

```
 echo ("email when = "+env.EMAIL_WHEN+ " always = "+email_when.ALWAYS);

 if (env.EMAIL_WHEN == email_when.ALWAYS)
 {
      echo ("Send email.")       
 }
 else
 {
    echo ("NO EMAIL")
 }
```

So this always prints

```
email when = 1 always = 1
NO EMAIL
```

I don't understand why?
I thought maybe it was some sort of object/value comparison thing?  Although I am directly setting env.EMAIL_WHEN  to email_when.ALWAYS.

I tried this and it still did the same thing:

```
if (env.EMAIL_WHEN.equals(email_when.ALWAYS))
```

Can anyone explain what I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Everything in `env` map automatically converted to strings so `1 != '1'`

Comment: ah, thank you! you should have posted it as an answer so I could mark it as the best!

Answer (score 2):

In Jenkins all the values of `env` map automatically converted to `String`

so `1 != '1'`

Comment: May I add a simple fix: `if (env.EMAIL_WHEN as int == email_when.ALWAYS)`